# SQLite3 output in reverse order latest 10 records

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

I need the last 10 records. The issue is the way it outputs, since starts from latest to oldest and I need oldest to new ones. See below

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM raw_all_sensors order by timestamp desc LIMIT 10;
2022-03-10 16:43:58|26.43|19.19|1014|56.81|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:38:57|26.49|19.19|1014|55.22|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:33:56|26.58|19.19|1014|55.67|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:28:55|26.68|19.19|1014|56.08|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:23:54|26.77|19.19|1014|55.72|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:18:52|26.88|19.19|1014|56.49|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:13:51|26.99|19.19|1014|56.47|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:08:50|27.07|19.19|1014|56.04|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:03:49|27.14|19.19|1014|55.98|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 15:58:48|27.3|19.19|1014|56.37|0|0|813|0
```

But I need

```
2022-03-10 15:58:48|27.3|19.19|1014|56.37|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:03:49|27.14|19.19|1014|55.98|0|0|813|0
2022-03-10 16:08:50|27.07|19.19|1014|56.04|0|0|813|0
...
```

How can I do this?

If I do `asc` (instead of `desc`), it starts from oldest records and is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   raw_all_sensors
        ORDER  BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT  10) t
ORDER  BY timestamp;
```

Basically getting the 10 rows you want in a derived table, then ordering them in an ascending way in the outer query.

Comment: What is the `t` on the second line of code in `... desc limit 10) t`? I used the sql query without the `t` and it worked just fine.

Comment: That is true, in sqlite it would work fine. But in some other DBMS it might not. For example in mysql every derived table must have an alias, so you'd get an error if you try to run it without the alias (doesn't have to be `t` of course, it can be anything).